# Disappearing top.links while refreshing the page second time if enabling the FPC

Tags: magento-1.8, full-page-cache, block-cache

I had installed Lesti_FPC module in my website. Recently we had made lot of design changes with the website. Then those changes are migrated to live. After migrating, the top links are disappearing when I refresh the home page in the second time.
I tried flush the magento cache, clear the cache and deleting the cache folder via FTP. Even after those efforts, top links are disappearing.

I checked the Lesti_FPC module. top.links is added to the lazy blocks. I dont know how to get the top.links fixedly seen in the pages.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Lesti FPC configuration in `System > Configuration > System > Lesti FPC` and try moving the `top.links` block from "Lazy Blocks" to "Bypass Handles".

Comment: thankx, it Works.

Answer (score 2):

May be below link will help you to understand the lazy and dynamic blocks in Lesti_FPC module.

https://gordonlesti.com/what-are-lazy-and-dynamic-blocks-in-lesti-fpc/